# Import table to DataFrame and set group of column as list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table (Tab delimited .txt file) in the following form:

- each row is an entry;
- first row are headers
- the first 5 columns are simple numeric parameters
- all column after the 7th column are supposed to be a list of values

My problem is how can I import and create a data frame where the last column contain a list of values?

**-----Problem 1 ----**

The header (first row) is "shorter", containing simply the name of some columns. All the values after the 7th do not have a header (because it is suppose to be a list). If I import the file as is, this appear to confuse the import functions

If, for example, I import as follow

```py
df = pd.read_table( path , sep="\t")
```

the `DataFrame` created has only as many columns as the elements in the first row. Moreover, the data value assigned are mismatched.

**---- Problem 2 -----**

What is really confusing to me is that if I open the .txt in Excel and save it as Tab-delimited (without changing anything), I can then import it without problems, with headers too: columns with no header are simply given an “Unnamed XYZ” tag.
Why would saving in Excel change it? Using Note++ I can see only one difference: the original .txt is in "Unix (LF)" form, while the one saved in Excel is "Windows (CR LF)". Both are UTF-8, so I do not understand how this would be an issue?!?

Nevertheless, from here I could manipulate the data and try to gather all columns I wish and make them into a list. However, I hope that there is a more elegant and faster way to do it.

Here is a screen-shot of the .txt file

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Can you attach a small snippet that illustrates the first row (the header) and the second row? Also, do you use the same delimiter between the columns 1-6 and 7 onwards?

Comment: I added a screen-shot of the data.
It is all tab delimited: originally created in Matlab using "\t" to separate line elements, and "\n" for newline

Comment: you can import with the parameter `skiprows`: `pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', skiprows=5,header=None)`. `header=None` may requires you to pass `names=[list_of_column_names]`.